# Best way to find data in json by jquery

Tags: jquery, json

i tried this but did not work and getting error **SyntaxError: invalid property id**

js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/mm49u6wv/

```
var data={
 { "Id": "12345", "Name": "Acme Widget 1", "Price": "£25.99", "Status": "In Stock"  },
 { "Id": "67890", "Name": "Acme Widget 2", "Price": "£28.99", "Status": "In Stock"  },
 { "Id": "11123", "Name": "Acme Widget 3", "Price": "£15.99", "Status": "In Stock"  },
 { "Id": "14156", "Name": "Acme Widget 4", "Price": "£33.99", "Status": "In Stock"  }
}

$.each(data, function(i, v) {
    alert(v.id);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keys are case sensitive so `id` and `Id` are different. Also correct your JSON array. Try this:

```
var data= [
 { "Id": "12345", "Name": "Acme Widget 1", "Price": "£25.99", "Status": "In Stock"  },
 { "Id": "67890", "Name": "Acme Widget 2", "Price": "£28.99", "Status": "In Stock"  },
 { "Id": "11123", "Name": "Acme Widget 3", "Price": "£15.99", "Status": "In Stock"  },
 { "Id": "14156", "Name": "Acme Widget 4", "Price": "£33.99", "Status": "In Stock"  }
];

$.each(data, function(i, v) {
    alert(v.Id);
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mm49u6wv/3/).

Comment: @Mou Still same mistake `id`. It should be `Id`.

Answer (score 2):

Your json array is invalid it should be :

```
var data=[
 { "Id": "12345", "Name": "Acme Widget 1", "Price": "£25.99", "Status": "In Stock"  },
 { "Id": "67890", "Name": "Acme Widget 2", "Price": "£28.99", "Status": "In Stock"  },
 { "Id": "11123", "Name": "Acme Widget 3", "Price": "£15.99", "Status": "In   Stock"  },
 { "Id": "14156", "Name": "Acme Widget 4", "Price": "£33.99", "Status": "In Stock"  }
];
```

and inside $.each id should be Id :

```
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
alert(v.Id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you created invalid JSON array. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/mm49u6wv/1/)

```
  var data=[
    { "Id": "12345", "Name": "Acme Widget 1", "Price": "£25.99", "Status": "In Stock"  },
    { "Id": "67890", "Name": "Acme Widget 2", "Price": "£28.99", "Status": "In Stock"  },
    { "Id": "11123", "Name": "Acme Widget 3", "Price": "£15.99", "Status": "In Stock"  },
    { "Id": "14156", "Name": "Acme Widget 4", "Price": "£33.99", "Status": "In Stock"  }
];


 $.each(data, function(i, v) {
   alert(v.Id);
 });
```

As mentioned in @Beginner answer you need to take care of key case. Keys are case sensitive